# Bilibili embedded iframe playback control

Tags: javascript, automation, youtube

This is an example of the [Bilibili](http://bilibili.com) embedded player. https://jsfiddle.net/6ych2ptj/

```
<iframe src="//player.bilibili.com/player.html?aid=883409884&bvid=BV1PK4y1b7dt&cid=201056987&page=1" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" allowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

What would be a good start point to achieve playback controls for these embedded iframe videos similar to [Youtube's iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)? There are no official API publicly available.

I have achieved this using Selenium but is it possible using **only** JavaScript? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have the same question. Have you had any progress? Thanks